# Dependency was not found: * module in ./node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.dev.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dependencies, server-side-rendering

I am trying to implement ssr and I get the following error:

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error                                                                         16:11:16

This dependency was not found:

* module in ./node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.dev.js

To install it, you can run: npm install --save module
```

In the main.js file I have the following code:

```
const app = new Vue({
        i18n,
        router: routerInstance,
        render: h => h(App),
    }).$mount('#app')

    const renderer = require('vue-server-renderer').createRenderer({
        template: require('fs').readFileSync('./index.template.html', 'utf-8')
    })

    renderer.renderToString(app, (err, html) => {
        console.log(html) // will be the full page with app content injected.
    })
```

[image]

Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: Were you able to solve the issue?